# Best way of rendering a chart in a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new in web programming and just want to ask for an opinion. I want to develop a web page and in the home page, I want to display a kind of chart. With nodes connected with arrows and the arrows will be hyperlinked. In a window based application, I understand there are tools like Visual Basic Power Tools in which you can drag and drop shapes like lines and oval or arrows and using there, it is fairly easy to make a chart.

But in a web application, I can't find any tools or anything that can help me draw a chart. Is there any recommendation on some kind of tools or something so that I can draw a chart in a web page? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it either client side or server side.

**Client side**

There are some javascript libraries which will render charts to your web page(Client side) upon feeding it with the data in JSON format. Checkout [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). Chart.js uses HTML5 canvas elements to draw the chart where d3 uses SVG for drawing charts.

**Server side**

ASP.NET has some charting libraries/server controls which renders charts for you. Check out [this blogpost](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) which has sample code to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. But all of the charts in provided in the library is graph chart. What I have in mind is a really simple flow chart. Nodes connected by arrows. Just to display in my home page and there will be a hyperlink for each arrows.